# search /replace text in html files with python

Tags: python, html, scripting, utf-16, utf

I'm trying to search and replace text inside multiple html files with the code below, it works with .txt, not with the html converted to .txt.
Is it a utf-16 problem? How could i make it work?

```
import os
directory ="/Users/sinanatra/PYTHON_STUFF/MSN/0/"

replacement = "test"
for dname, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for fname in files:
        fpath = os.path.join(dname, fname)
        with open(fpath) as f:
            s = f.read()
        s = s.replace("head", replacement)
        with open(fpath, "w") as f:
            f.write(s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use utf-16 then you need

`s.read().decode('utf-16')` and for write you will need:

`f.write(s.encode('utf16'))`